# How to remove the gap on right side of webpage (using Bootstrap with WordPress)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This padding on the right side of the webpage ([unityinfinity.com](https://www.unityinfinity.com)) was not visible when it was in development. I recently shifted the website to the main directory using the steps in [this post](https://askwpgirl.com/move-wordpress-from-subdirectory-to-root-directory/). 
Since then, there is that horrendous padding as well as issues with responsiveness.

I am using Elementor page builder for individual pages and Bootstrap (for styling and responsiveness). During development, the website was functioning correctly (there was no gap on the right side of the page).

However, now, the website has issues with responsiveness and there's a huge padding/margin on the right side if you try to check how it looks on different devices.

I can't pinpoint where the issue is (Elementor doesn't let me stretch the sections to overlap with the padding), so probably Bootstrap is the culprit.

Thanks for your help!

---

Edit: I tried uploading the theme to a local environment and uploading some pages to test it out. It runs just fine over there.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by fixing your JS errors.  Without digging to deep into this my guess is that when you moved over the site you have some incorrect file paths to your JS files.  Fix these errors and there is a good chance it will fix whatever other issues you are having.

I'm pretty sure the grid_gallery error is the reason your responsive styles are whack.

[image]

Comment: Hi,

The grid gallery error has been there ever since the website was in development. I'm pretty sure this isn't the issue.

Comment: every time you resize the browser its throwing the error, so I would fix it or get rid of it.  What about the other errors?  Are they also in your dev setup?

Comment: I got rid of the grid_gallery error now. Yes, the other error is also present in my dev setup. The js is not an issue I guess. It's got something to do with bootstrap, but I can't understand what

Comment: An error in the console is an issue per definition. Beside that, your page throws a 403 Forbidden error page, so I can't say anything else.